# More Efficient method to split overlapped intervals, then merge duplicates

Tags: arrays, typescript, intervals

So I'm trying to figure out the most efficient method to split overlapped intervals, then merge duplicates. Two conditions specific to my situation are that if the start of a merged interval was an end of an original interval, it is incremented by 1. If the end of a merged interval was a start of an original interval, it is decremented by 1. Here is some sample data, and the expected result:

```
interface Interval {
    start: number;
    end: number;
    type: Array<number>;
}

// starting data
const arr: Array<Interval> = [
    { start: 0, end: 16, type: [42] },
    { start: 6, end: 30, type: [95] },
    { start: 11, end: 24, type: [126] },
    { start: 32, end: 47, type: [42] }
].sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start);

// magic splitting code here

// what we expect to end up with
const end_arr: Array<Interval> = [
    { start: 0, end: 5, type: [42] },
    { start: 6, end: 10, type: [42, 95] },
    { start: 11, end: 16, type: [42, 95, 126] },
    { start: 17, end: 24, type: [95, 126] },
    { start: 25, end: 30, type: [95] },
    { start: 32, end: 47, type: [42] },
];
```

I've already technically got an answer for this, but it is not very efficient - involving 3 nested for/forEach loops. Surely there is a more efficient way? Here is the code for that:

```
let startIndexArray: Array<number> = [];

let endIndexArray: Array<number> = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    startIndexArray.push(arr[i].start);
    endIndexArray.push(arr[i].end);
}

startIndexArray = startIndexArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);
endIndexArray = endIndexArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);

const indexArray = [...startIndexArray, ...endIndexArray].sort((a, b) => a - b);

const result: Array<Interval> = [];

arr.forEach((currentInterval) => {
    for (let i = currentInterval.start; i < currentInterval.end; i++) {
        if (indexArray.includes(i)) {
            const position = indexArray.indexOf(i);

            if (position !== indexArray.length - 1) {
                let start = i;
                let next = indexArray[position + 1];

                if (endIndexArray.includes(start)) {
                    start = start + 1;
                }

                if (startIndexArray.includes(next)) {
                    next = next - 1;
                }

                let in_result = false;
                result.forEach((mergedInterval) => {
                    if (mergedInterval.start === start && mergedInterval.end === next) {
                        mergedInterval.type = [...mergedInterval.type, ...currentInterval.type];
                        in_result = true;
                    }
                });
                if (!in_result) {
                    result.push({ start: start, end: next, type: [...currentInterval.type]});
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

// output is my expected, correct outcome
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is efficiency an actual concern for your use case? Is the array likely to contain many thousands of intervals spanning many thousands of time steps?  I ask because correctness is often more important than performance, and a "naive" implementation of this, shown [here](https://repl.it/@jcalz/TintedDeterminedBudgetrange), where you unroll the interval array into a series of time steps and then re-roll them back to intervals, might well perform acceptably and is much less likely to suffer from bizarre edge cases than a more efficient version suggested on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jcalz this algorithm gets called as part of a larger process that is potentially called on hundreds or thousands of pieces of data that then need to be presented to the user as soon as possible - thus this step should be efficient. The solution you've linked is slower than my original code.

Comment: Can you specify the exact input-output relationship?  Are `start` and `end` always non-negative integers?  What should happen if the input intervals overlap or meet for the same `type`?  e.g., `[{ start: 0, end: 10, type: [42] },{ start: 5, end: 12, type: [42] }]` or `[{ start: 0, end: 10, type: [42] },{ start: 11, end: 12, type: [42] }]`?

Comment: I expect [this](https://repl.it/@jcalz/ForkedWorldlyTitles) to be faster; not sure about edge cases though. Let me know if that works for you and I'll write it up as an answer. Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: Start and end are always non-negative, and input intervals of the same type will never overlap. Your new solution is indeed 3-4 times faster than my original code, thanks! I haven't found any edge cases when tested against my sample inputs, so it looks like it works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following algorithm is the cleanest one I can come up with which has reasonable performance.  I expect that, with the particular example array you gave, this code and the one you gave above will be of similar performance levels, but if you start using larger arrays you will see performance gains here compared to yours.  Without a suite of test cases it's hard to tell for sure.

Anyway, the general idea looks like this. Let's call a `Partition` a sorted array of non-overlapping intervals that covers all integers from `-Infinity` to `Infinity`.

```
type Partition = Array<Interval>;
```

If we have a value `partition` of type `Partition`, we know that `partition[0].start === -Infinity`, `partition[partition.length-1].end === Infinity`, and for any index `i < partition.length - 1`, `partition[i].end + 1 === partition[i+1].start`.

---

One good thing about a partition is that it will always contain exactly one interval that covers any given `position`.  This eliminates a class of edge cases.  So, given a `partition: Partition` and a `position: number`, let's find the index of the interval inside `partition` that contains it:

```
// binary search of the partition to find the index of the interval containing position
// startIndex is a hint, where partition[startIndex].start <= position
// endIndex is a hint, where partition[startIndex].end > position
function findIndex(
    partition: Partition,
    position: number,
    startIndex: number = 0,
    endIndex: number = partition.length
) {
    while (true) {
        let i = (startIndex + endIndex) >> 1;
        let cur = partition[i];
        if (cur.end <= position) {
            startIndex = i;
        } else if (cur.start > position) {
            endIndex = i;
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

This algorithm is a binary search, and it allows you to give it hints about start and end index if you happen to already have some knowledge about where in the partition the right interval might be.  If the partition is of length  then this algorithm should be ( ).

---

Another useful operation is to split a `partition` at a particular `position`.  If the partition already contains an interval starting at the position, you don't have to do anything.  Otherwise you need to find the interval that spans the position and split it into two:

```
// ensure that the partition contains an interval starting at position
// startIndex is a hint, where partition[startIndex].start <= position
// return the index of the interval starting at position
function splitAt(partition: Partition, position: number, startIndex: number = 0) {

    let i = findIndex(partition, position, startIndex);
    let cur = partition[i];
    if (cur.start < position) {
        partition.splice(i, 1,
            { start: cur.start, end: position - 1, type: cur.type.slice() },
            { start: position, end: cur.end, type: cur.type }
        )
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

This algorithm uses `findIndex()` so it should also be ( ). (edit... I guess this depends on `splice()`, so it's possibly just ()).

---

Given a `partition: Partition` and an `interval: Interval`, how can we merge the interval into the partition?  We need to split the partition at the interval's `start` and just after the interval's `end` positions, and then walk through the affected intervals and add the new interval's `type` array to them:

```
// merge interval into partition
function merge(partition: Partition, interval: Interval) {
    // split partition at interval's start, get index of starting interval in partition
    let startIndex = splitAt(partition, interval.start);
    // split partition at interval's end, get index of interval after ending interval
    let endIndex = splitAt(partition, interval.end + 1, startIndex);
    // add types to each interval between start and end
    for (let i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
        partition[i].type.push(...interval.type);
    }
}
```

This is a pair of binary searches plus a walk through affected intervals.  In the worst case each interval in the partition needs to be modified, so this would be ().

---

Finally, all we need to do to convert an arbitrary array of intervals into the format you'd like is to start with an empty `Partition` (which has exactly one interval from `-Infinity` to `Infinity` and with an empty `type` array), merge each interval into it, and then return the final `Partition` *without any intervals whose `type` array is empty*.  This will automatically suppress the ones that touch `Infinity` or `-Infinity`, as well as any holes in the middle:

```
// denormalize array into non-overlapping intervals
function denormalize(arr: Array<Interval>) {

    // empty partition
    const partition: Partition = [{ start: -Infinity, end: Infinity, type: [] }];
    arr.forEach(interval => merge(partition, interval));
    // turn partition into normal array by removing "empty" intervals
    return partition.filter(i => i.type.length !== 0);
}
```

Since this runs `merge()` for each interval, this will end up being (²) in the worst case.  I think that's probably the best you can do for the algorithm; this implies that you shouldn't need three nested loops but I'd be surprised if you can avoid having two.

---

You can verify that it produces the same output as your version. There may be edge cases but I'm more confident with an algorithm that operates on `Partition`s since I don't have to keep asking "what if the position I'm looking at doesn't have an interval associated with it"?

---

Notes:

- You might want to consider having your intervals be half-open as in `[start, end)`.  That is, `start` should be the smallest position contained by the interval and `end` should be the smallest position *greater* than the interval.  Half-open intervals are much easier to compose and reason about.  The length of `[start, end)` is `end - start`.  If you join intervals `[a, b)` and `[b, c)` you get `[a, c)`. If you ever decide that you need to switch from whole number positions to fractions, a half-open interval won't require any code changes.  Conversely, closed intervals require careful math to add or subtract `1` (or whatever the step size is) in the right places and are therefore susceptible to fence-post errors.
- As I said before, performance is often important but it might not be as important as correctness.  The only way to know exactly how important performance is in your case is to test it against load and see how it fares.  Quite often a simple algorithm is preferable to a complicated one that is a little faster, especially if you have to maintain and/or debug the code in the future.

---

All right, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngHgCoB8yA3gFDIXKgIA2ArgCYQDOAFMxHFAgBYCiNCAFsI4AFzI8AGmQwoAeyEBJEEwAeAfgkg6QgEbQAlBL3z5guCADcpUgF9SoSLEQoVzgG5waJcpWZgXGDaugZQNpTIogwh+tARlGBYAA4QEuiYuDpxUAQ2DqQA9IXIAUGgAObIDHCBpAjyIAHIXFDpGNg47tBeNEQAvMgA2n4UxKWBUMHIAAwy0RIAjABsMkmpEkMALABMALrIdlKjJBNBEjvzqksAHGspacO7MwdHJ+NlUxKrUdfIAMxzZDrR5DACcAFZXsdIh9JtNFosrjFkDstvcNsNFjtltD3mcvgDLr8UVsAOwY0G7PGwgnTf4Q5EXLZAkGbbE0yhw87IRYzIELVEQ1kPTY3G6vWx7GxFEpMEDyKBCbzAABeKFa2Co4HkyAVIAAtPIPNAaHBkslKtrPN5mKQYHQQAgwMBGtVRIrlTQ1RBWK12pkuuAet4CIZfCditbRNM4MhkuUXW7gMwWqVFZAGC0OlhkPIYHrGkaTVAzRarU4QzRU5GSg0S1bvD5KxVoKm5IpkAaVDBQMAksDdT2+0kTiDkAAFROukDIQYZTrdKC9PK2SJRvSgLi5jhcXh5gtgHgoBNTfszweyUBZo8oa8QNQH4HH6PL7zIBrgOB9kBVZLyZhz0aWs6RUdQqFTOMeCcGQAHdjygE9p0aIZPjAMCHz2AA6NDkBwQZ-0ApMQBA6IMMfFM02g8A4IQpCz2I1D4XI7DomQIhCKAkjIgdJ1iKvVRyNYE5IlPF1iIkKcGJnGFIkoTiJL1UJoFkuTQNUB9YjCOdZlUuSyI0tQtOgHSxK4rDBF-I8TnDMg1IoeDgEEZBWDAKA6AgWyRPswQwCoHT2GYwzkAAahJcjwwIIhFgSezKF8j86CgUzkJAIZgGlby1OAAtWAQJKsLY-D4wArivLiuK0PInTgFiiq7Cias71y-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-I4HCoZLBwBA4VzioPdK2FLbJDoMwHgrAsK0JfiCb+9lQ5LVIkIZIA5B4nE-M0Qehd846SGLraY3YQBM37FgQ2w4QDiI9kMV4mVIitCwsgqAfBEDUPAf0IgOdfRPz7oYRhFAowRwHnXJwuoFRKnfJqXMehcyISEMaK0AAiYQ7CsDOL7naSIoNI613zsopyzh1ZziIMALCltLIVCPMgAAhP0QYNN8i2FIAlAAcjpPk-J+QyntJnfikAAioBoBURU-YeBCD9CUiQrAjJoBzEGG0fRwxaPqYGMuoZn4ogCFASoFcEqIWYAGRcF9QwCIUZQbh5gIAROACIdWDBDGyBQawNBiT8EyzSfgwhk17KDJ0t4CofoMBLOYVMwQsyRB8FUAspZ5yZk0HkEcgAUgAZQAPJpPar038OUsCsEGQY5JpBCmYxKWUo8lSykVC3DQAAIh6Kx3p1TFNKb0yFMhnHQthS0cF6KKnOMXqC1FEKKmsHlJ6FU6pMUgAgLBXFaLylCEJTKZG-FsUgG8AiyxXofQkvxZU-0bSRlNLDLsigCUKYPgXFgYZWRlK5HGTKPm19mbqBlXKnA2QwgDGGJlJGKy1mzA2TgpRUSjzbJCkQ-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)

Comment: Thanks for the help, though I've noticed that the second solution you proposed [here](https://repl.it/@jcalz/ForkedWorldlyTitles) actually performs better than this solution - I guess this is the case of performance vs correctness